# Can I recover my lost R&D materials?

Tags: let-it-die

There isn't much documentation on this game since it came out recently but does anyone know if I can recover lost R&D materials if I kill my past self? Also can I recover them if I am two generations from that hater?

Basically this was the situation:

1. Lvl 7 me (character A) had a bunch of R&D materials
2. I died and didn't have the credits to use the revive service (had already used the free one)
3. Got a new character (character B) and that one died almost immediately

Can I still recover the lost materials from Character A with my Character C (current instance).

I am sure it was probably mentioned in the tutorial messages but I skimmed most of those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, earn more kill coins and buy back character A. Do it before character A is killed as a hater and lost forever, though.